# Derivative exists when limit of derivative exists

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ be continuous on $(a,b)$ and let $c\in(a,b)$. Suppose $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\in(a,b)\backslash\{c\}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)$ exists. Prove that $f'(c)$ exists.

I don't know what to do on this other than follow definitions. So for all $x\in(a,b)\backslash\{c\}$, the limit $$\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$ exists, and moreover, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$ exists. To prove is that $$\lim_{y\rightarrow c}\frac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}$$ exists.

Comment: See the first answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422392/differentiability-of-a-function-at-a-point-to-prove-it-differentiable-everywhere) post.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277083/how-to-show-f0-exist-and-is-equal-to-1?rq=1) has good answers as well (easily generalized).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you, nice proof.