# $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=L$ implies $f'(c)=L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$ and let $c \in(a,b)$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=L$ some $L \in\mathbb{R}$. Without using L'Hospital's Rule, prove that $f'(c)=L$.
Hint: Use the Mean Value Theorem and the e-d definition of f'(c).

Any leads would be much appreaciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the hint you already have? Did you try to use it? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx/257936) for ideas.

Comment: @DavidMitra i'm not sure where i have to use the epsilon-delta definiton of f'(c) here.

Answer (score 8):

Let $x>c$. By the Mean Value Theorem in $[c,x]$,
$$\exists \xi_x\in [c,x]\text{ so that }f'(\xi_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
Now as $x\to c^+$, $\xi_x\to c^+$ and so...

Can you complete the proof now?

EDIT: With $\epsilon-\delta$: Let $\epsilon>0$. Then 
$$\exists \delta>0\text{ so that }c<y<c+\delta\implies \left|f'(y)-L\right|<\epsilon$$
As we saw above, for $x\in (c,c+\delta)$, $\exists \ y\in (c,x)\subseteq (c,c+\delta)$ so that
$$f'(y)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
But then,
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L\right|<\epsilon$$
whenever $c<x<c+\delta$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Hi i'm not sure where i have to use the epsilon-delta definiton of f'(c) here.

Comment: @tal Look at the edited answer