# Error in the derivative proof

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-verification, fake-proofs

Assume $h$ is a function on an open interval $K$, and differentiable on $K$. Therefore $h'$ is cont on $K$.

The faulty proof goes as follows:

Let $a\in K$

By the definition of the derivative:

$$h'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}$$

Since $h$ is cont, limit of numerator is $0$, same goes for denominator. Since $h$ is diff, we can apply LH rule.

$$h'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}\to(LH)\to \lim_{x\to a}\frac{h'(x)-0}{1-0}=\lim_{x\to a}h'(x)$$

We have proven that $h'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}h'(x)$. By defn, $h'$ is cont.

---

There is an error in the proof, and I also need to fix the proof.

I don't see something right away.

My guess is that $x-a\neq 0$, but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88076/discussion-on-question-by-k-split-x-error-in-the-derivative-proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hospital's rule says that **if** $f'/g'$ converges to a limit $A$ (and some other assumptions are fulfilled), then also $f/g \to A$.

In your “proof”, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} h'(x)$ need not exist.

(But if it does, then the claim is true: [Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx))

Comment: By need not exist, do you mean infinity?

Comment: No, I mean “not exist”. Like for the standard example $h(x) = x^2 \sin(x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $h(0)=0$, where $h'(x)$ will oscillate as $x \to 0$, so that there is no limit (neither finite nor infinite).

Comment: Oops, that should have been $h(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$, of course.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the exact flaw. Also the argument used by asker proves that if the limit of derivative exists then derivative is continuous. This is very special of derivatives that they can't have what is usually called simple / jump discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=0$, $h(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin {1 \over x} , & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x = 0\end{cases}$ on $K=(-1,1)$. Then $h$ is differentiable on $K$ but ${h(x) \over x}$ has no limit as $x \to 0$.