# A question on differentiability at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is a continuous function differentiable at $x=c$ if the limit of its derivative has a value at that point? That is, if $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f'(x) = L = \lim_{x \rightarrow c^+} f'(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow c^-} f'(x)$$

Intuitively, the slopes of the tangents approach the same value and since the function is continuous a jump-discontinuity isn't possible so it appears the slope at the point should be $L$ too. However, I cannot seem to locate such a theorem, so I suspect my intuition is wrong. Is it?

Comment: In your expressions, you are assuming $f$ is differentiable on some neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3923258/334795. I answered this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=A$ then $f'(c)=A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923258/if-lim-x-to-cfx-a-then-fc-a)

Comment: Thanks @Hermis14, this indeed answers my question.

Comment: Yes, @IamWill, I assume the function is differentiable at the neighberhood.