# Prove that $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, functions, exponential-function

I am trying to prove that this function is bijective, but I don't know how to do it.

> $$f:x \mapsto \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

For that, I try to use the fact that this function has necessarily a reciprocal if it is bijective. 
So, I think I need to prove that :
$$f(x)=y \Leftrightarrow x = f^{-1}(y)$$ 
If I understand correctly, this means that : 
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x} = y \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{y}{e^y-1}$$

But my problem is that I don't know how to do this, and I don't know if there is a more efficient way to solve the problem. 
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You won't find a reciprocal in closed form. Instead, show it is continuous, injective and unbounded.

Comment: Ok, so to prove that the function is continuous, it is not very hard, I think. Then, to prove that it is injective, I suppose I need to introduce a new function g(x) = e^x and compute the derivative of g(x), right ? But finally, how can I prove that this is unbounded ? I mean, $0 \leq f(x)$, no ?

Comment: And no, it is **not** true that $y=\frac{e^x-1}x$ iff $x=\frac{y}{e^y-1}.$

Comment: By the way, the function is undefined at $x=0,$ so you need to define it there caerfully to make the function continuous.

Comment: Yes, my bad ^^" ! But how can I prove that the function is unbounded ?

Comment: I don't know, is it unbounded? Does the question say what it is a bijection with?

Comment: I need to prove that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$, and that $f(0) = 1$

Comment: Then you don't need unbounded below, just that as $x\to -\infty,$ $f(x)\to0.$

Comment: So, if I prove that $x \rightarrow - \inf, f(x) \rightarrow 0$, and $x \rightarrow + \inf, f(x) \rightarrow + \inf$, and that $f(x)$ is continuous and that $f$ is injective, am I good ?

Comment: The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ gets to $0$ is just the definition of the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @markvs It seems that the task is to prove that the function is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^+$. Of course, in its current form this is not true either because $1$ is not in the range of $f$. OP, please write precisely in the question how you define $f(x)$ for $x=0$ and between what sets you have to prove bijectivity.

Comment: Your $\frac{e^x-1}{x} = y \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{y}{e^y-1}$ is wrong.Your function $f$ as bijection has a reciprocal function whose graphic is symmetric to $f$ respect to the diagonal $y=x$. You can have many points of $f^{-1}$. For example you have points for all natural $n$
$$\left(\ln(n),\frac{n-1}{\ln(n)}\right)\in f\iff \left(\frac{n-1}{\ln(n)},\ln(n)\right)\in f^{-1}$$ You can verify this way the error of your equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Let us add some more structure. Consider the function $f: \R\setminus\{0\} \to \R_{+}\setminus \{1\}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^x -1}{x}
$$
and define its extension $g:\R \to \R_{+}$ where $g(0) = 1$. We can easily show that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$ by L'Hopital's rule.

Now consider the derivative of $g$,

$$
g'(x) = \frac{e^x(x-1) +1}{x^2}
$$

We have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Hence from [Hermis14](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3923280/334795), $g'(0) = 1/2$.

Furthurmore, $g'(x)$ is always positive and $g$ is surjective, which means $g$ is bijective.

Therefore, $f$ is bijective.

Comment: The range of $f$ is $\mathbb R^+ \setminus \left\{ 1\right\}$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you. I corrected it.

Comment: Your statement, "Furthermore, $g'(x)$ is always positive, which means $g(x)$ is bijective," is incorrect.  For instance, $\arctan(x)$ has positive derivative everywhere, but is not a bijective function from reals to reals.  Having a positive derivative only shows that $g$ is injective.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Thanks for the comment. I added some phrases.

Comment: What is a "subjective" function? Do you mean surjective?

Comment: @Gary I was so sleepy... Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to notice that
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x} = \int_0^1 e^{x t} d t$$
so the function $f$ and all its derivatives are $>0$, with $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \infty$.

Obs: The reciprocal $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is the generating function of the Bernoulli numbers

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}.$ Then, the claim follows immediately from the following easily verified facts:

$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},\ \underset {x\to \infty}\lim f(x)=\infty,\ \underset {x\to -\infty}\lim f(x)=0\ $ and $f'(x)=\dfrac{\left(x-1\right)e^x+1}{x^2}>0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$