# If $ f$ is continuous on $ [a,b] $ and differentiable on $ (a,b) $ does this imply $f'_{+}(a)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Question:** If $f$ is continuous on $ [a,b] $ and differentiable on $ (a,b) $ does this imply $f'_{+}(a)\in \mathbb{R} $  exist?

I'm not sure, here's a counter-example when $ f $ is not continuous on $ [a,b] $:
Let $ f(x) = 1/x $ for all $ x \in (0,1) $. Then $ f $ is differentiable on $ (0,1) $  but the right-hand sided limit at $ 0 $ ( i.e. the limit of $ f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ as $ x \to 0^+ $ ) does not exist.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The derivative of $ \sqrt{x} $  does not have limit at $ 0^+ $

Comment: Also $f(x)=x\sin\frac1x$ on $[0,1],$ if you want q case where $f’(0)=\infty$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Ok, I haven't thought of that counter-example. You are right, the function is continuous on $ [0,1] $ and differentiable on $ (0,1] $ but the limit does not exist at $ 0^+ $.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $f'_{a^+}(x)$? That's some very strange notation...

Comment: @HansLundmark You are right, I meant to write  $ f'_{+}(a)=  lim_{x \to a^+}  \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} $ , sorry...

Comment: OK. But note that $f'_+(a)$ is *not* necessarily equal to $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$. The former may exist even if the latter doesn't (but not the other way around if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx) for example).