# differentiability on the endpoint of a interval.

Tags: analysis, differential, mean-value-theorem

**Exercise**:
Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. Also assume that $f $ is differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$. Assume that there exists a number $ c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f’(x) \to c$ for $x \to$ $a_+$ . Show that $f$ is differentiable at the endpoint $a$ with
$f’(a) = c$.

**My solution** (which is not correct according to professor):

In the definition of continuity in the point $a$ $\Delta x \in (0, b-a)$.
We are asked to show:
\begin{align}
    &\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} =  \frac{\Delta f}{x-a}\rightarrow c, \hspace{3mm} \Delta x= x-a \rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow f'(a) = c\\
    &\Rightarrow \frac{\Delta f}{x-a} \rightarrow c, \hspace{3mm} x \rightarrow a_+ \label{eq: differentiabilitet_specielt} 
\end{align}
But since the first equation holds for $ x \in [a,b] \setminus \{ a\}$, the left implication is specially true in point a. Which means the two expressions are equvialent for our case.

I would like to understand why my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx)

Comment: I’m interested in understanding why my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect because it is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in(a,b)$ and by the mean value theorem there exists some $y\in(a,x)$, s.t. $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(y)$$Now let $x\to a$, which implies $y\to a$ and we get $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{y\to a}f'(y)=c$$i.e. f is differentiable in a and $f'(a)=c$.

Comment: I know this solution. But I want to know why my solution is incorrect.