# Applications of $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

On a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx), Pete L. Clark wonders if there are any applications of $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$. Ben mentions one in the coments. I'm wondering if there are any other interesting usages of this, be it for particular functions or for proving other theorems.

Comment: So what are the applications of a continuous first derivative at $x=a$?