# Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $\lim_{x\to{a}} f^\prime(x)$ exists, show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, mean-value-theorem

I have some troubles in trying to prove the following result and possibly need some guidance:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $\lim_{x\to{a}} f^\prime(x)$ exists, show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$

**What I tried**. I started the proof as follows
If $x < b$, then $f$ is differentiable on $(a, x)$. So by the Mean Value theorem,
$$
f^\prime(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}.
$$ Now we want to show that $\lim\limits_{{x \to a}} \frac{{f(x) - f(a)}}{{x - a}}$ exists (and is equal to $L$), so we should estimate the difference
$$
\left| \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - L \right|=|f^\prime(c) - L|
$$
From now on I am not sure on what to do: any help would be very much appreciated.
**A note**. My professor specifically asked to prove the statement by using the Mean Value Theorem, so I can't use any solution revolving around L'Hopitals Rule.

Comment: The proof is just apply l hopital

Comment: We haven't learnt lhopitals rule in my real analysis class yet, my professor specifically asked us to prove it using the mean value theorem, sorry for the confusion ill edit my post

Comment: In that case, what you ve written is fine. Just send $x\searrow a$ and you are done

Comment: Assuming you are working with the formal $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, you just need to let $\varepsilon > 0$, get some $\delta > 0$ such that $a < c < a+\delta$ implies $|f'(c) - L|<\varepsilon$, and then let $x$ be such that $a <x < a+\delta$.

Comment: Yes this was my approach to the question, but im having difficulty finding the proper delta such that $|f'(c) - L| < \epsilon $

Comment: note that $c=c(x)\in(a,x)$. Then let $x\searrow a$

Comment: I was wondering if you could elaborate how that shows the function is differentiable  at a, I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: See the question [Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx) for various answers.

Comment: As for "how do we find $\delta$?" - Just use the assumption that the limit of $f'(x)$ exists as $x\to a$.